# Applying for a schengen Visa when not making a return trip

Tags: visas, schengen, trains, indian-citizens, europe

I'm planning to travel from Paris to Moscow by train. I'm an Indian so I have to apply for a Schengen visa. But the problem is that I'm planning to end my journey at Beijing while the Schengen visa asks for a Return flight ticket. What to do?

Comment: The application form does not ask about your return **flight** ticket. There might be a question about the end date of your visit. It's the day when you leave the Schengen area.

Comment: You have to show that you intend to leave the Schengen area; not that you'll return home. *However*, if you are leaving to a third country (China in your case), you should provide evidence that you'll be admitted to China. This can be a Chinese residence permit, a flight elsewhere, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement for a return flight ticket.  The requirement is to show evidence of your intention to leave the Schengen area.  That can be by air, by rail, or by any other means.